# Exception while running STS Client from WSO2 Identity Server

Tags: apache-axis, rampart, wso2-identity-server

I am new to WebServer Security and STS. I need to secure web services. My first target is to get the samples running.

As such I downloaded the STS-CLIENT from

svn co http://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/platform/branches/turing/products/is/5.0.0/modules/samples/sts/

as given in  : https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS500/Running+an+STS+Client

I can get the token from Identity Server. Then I try to invoke a 'echoString' service hosted in Tomcat.

But in tomcat , I get the following exception :

```
[ERROR] General security error (WSSecurityEngine: No crypto property file supplied for decryption)
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: General security error (WSSecurityEngine: No crypto property file supplied for decryption)
    at org.apache.rampart.handler.RampartReceiver.setFaultCodeAndThrowAxisFault(RampartReceiver.java:180)
    at org.apache.rampart.handler.RampartReceiver.invoke(RampartReceiver.java:95)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.Phase.invokeHandler(Phase.java:340)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.Phase.invoke(Phase.java:313)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.invoke(AxisEngine.java:262)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:168)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPTransportUtils.processHTTPPostRequest(HTTPTransportUtils.java:172)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.doPost(AxisServlet.java:146)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
```

Any help will be appreciated a lot.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<service name="sample05">
    <operation name="echoString">
        <messageReceiver class="org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCMessageReceiver"/>
    </operation>    
    <parameter name="ServiceClass" locked="false">org.apache.rampart.samples.policy.sample05.SimpleService</parameter>

    <module ref="rampart" />
    <module ref="addressing" />

    <wsp:Policy wsu:Id="SgnEncrAnonymous" xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy"
            xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
    <wsp:ExactlyOne>
        <wsp:All>
            <sp:SymmetricBinding xmlns:sp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy">
                <wsp:Policy>
                    <sp:ProtectionToken>
                        <wsp:Policy>
                            <sp:X509Token
                                    sp:IncludeToken="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy/IncludeToken/Never">
                                <wsp:Policy>
                                    <sp:RequireThumbprintReference/>
                                    <sp:WssX509V3Token10/>
                                </wsp:Policy>
                            </sp:X509Token>
                        </wsp:Policy>
                    </sp:ProtectionToken>
                    <sp:AlgorithmSuite>
                        <wsp:Policy>
                            <sp:Basic256/>
                        </wsp:Policy>
                    </sp:AlgorithmSuite>
                    <sp:Layout>
                        <wsp:Policy>
                            <sp:Lax/>
                        </wsp:Policy>
                    </sp:Layout>
                    <sp:IncludeTimestamp/>
                    <sp:OnlySignEntireHeadersAndBody/>
                </wsp:Policy>
            </sp:SymmetricBinding>
            <sp:SupportingTokens xmlns:sp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy">
                <wsp:Policy>
                    <sp:IssuedToken
                            sp:IncludeToken="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy/IncludeToken/AlwaysToRecipient">
                        <sp:Issuer>
                            <Address xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">https://localhost:9443/services/wso2carbon-sts</Address>
                        </sp:Issuer>
                        <sp:RequestSecurityTokenTemplate>
                            <t:TokenType xmlns:t="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/trust">urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion</t:TokenType>
                            <t:KeyType xmlns:t="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/trust">http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/trust/Bearer</t:KeyType>
                            <t:KeySize xmlns:t="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/trust">256</t:KeySize>
                            <t:Claims Dialect="http://wso2.org/claims"
                                      xmlns:t="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/trust"
                                      xmlns:ic="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity">
                                <ic:ClaimType Uri="http://wso2.org/claims/givenname"/>
                                <ic:ClaimType Uri="http://wso2.org/claims/emailaddress"/>
                            </t:Claims>
                        </sp:RequestSecurityTokenTemplate>
                        <wsp:Policy>
                            <sp:RequireInternalReference/>
                        </wsp:Policy>
                    </sp:IssuedToken>
                </wsp:Policy>
            </sp:SupportingTokens>
        </wsp:All>
    </wsp:ExactlyOne>
</wsp:Policy>
</service>
```

Comment: I have probably found what needs to be done here. The policy I listed down is from STS-Client source.  What needs to be configured in the rampart configuration to validate the SAML2 security header. I was working on Axis2 1.6.2 which had bug. So shifted to Axis 2 1.7 and rampart 1.7.0 . still having issues. Will post the solution soon